# Find an equation for a plane containing a line, orthogonal to another line

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

I was wondering if someone could give me directions on how to solve the following problem:

[image]

I've gotten the equations of the lines pretty easily, with the line that must be contained being represented as the following:
$$R_1=(0,1,-1)+T(1,3,2)$$
And the line to be orthogonal against being:
$$R_2=(1,-5,3)+U(-17,1,7) $$
But I'm stuck as to go from here. How do we define a plane using a line and a given point? How do we make that plane orthogonal to another line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plane's normal vector is *parallel* to the direction vector of $R_2$, which means its equation is
$$(-17,1,7)\cdot(x,y,z)=k$$
To find $k$, note that the starting point of $R_1$ $(0,1,-1)$ is in the plane:
$$(-17,1,7)\cdot(0,1,-1)=-6$$
So the equation of the plane is
$$-17x+y+7z=-6$$
As verification, we can check that $R_1$ and $R_2$'s direction vectors are perpendicular ($(1,3,2)\cdot(-17,1,7)=0$), implying that the plane contains $R_1$.

Comment: Right, so the direction vector of the line we want to be orthogonal to is what we need to use in the whole $n*r = n*r_0$ equation that describes a plane in order to get that orthogonal property happening. Subbing in the one known point on the line that needs to be on the plane yields the RHS, and we just simplify from there for the parametric.

Comment: @PixelRain Apparently, yes... I write $n\cdot r=k=n\cdot r_0$ though.